# Draw the four isomers of C2H2Cl2Br2

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

I have to draw the 4 four isomers for the molecule  $\ce {C2H2Cl2}$  when $\ce {Br2}$ is added to it. At last the four isomers for  $\ce {C2H2Cl2Br2}$.
I have found three of them:

[image]

I can't find the last one.

Comment: We would need to know what CH2Cl2 is before we can really answer.  Is it geminal, cis or trans?

Comment: @Lighthart The first structure is from geminal, the second is from cis and the third is trans (or do I have cis and trans backwards). The only other isomer I can think of is 1,1-dibromo-2,2-dichloroethane, but it is not made from adding Br2 to dichloroethene.

Comment: I understand which is which, but the OP does not indicate which molecule is his reactant (or that he has a mix of isomers as reactants

Answer (score 4):

You have only three isomers with the configurations (1R,2R), (1S,2S) and (1R,2S). The one with the configuration (1R,2S) is achiral, as it has a symmetry plan, and it's superimposable on its image by a mirror (i.e. it is identical to its enentiomer (1S,2R)).

This isomer is known as "meso compound".

Meso compounds are a special case of stereoisomers which occur when a molecule has two chiral centers and each chiral center has identical substituants.

[image]

Comment: The other are too meso compounds.

Comment: No, because they don't have a plan of symmetry like this one. Mine is the same as the one you have drawn on the right. We have drawn two conformers of the same molecule.

Answer (score 1):

Like Lighthart already mentioned in the comments, it is important to know which compound was used in the addition reaction. Because of the [reaction mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halogen_addition_reaction#Reaction_mechanism), only certain products are formed, this is very specific. LDC3 also explained that in the comments, but let me dissect this a little further.

> The first structure is from geminal,

In the scheme below, this is reaction $(1)$ and it forms an achiral product.

> the second is from cis

This is depicted in $(2)$ and it forms the meso compound described in Yomen Atassis's answer.

> and the third is trans (or do I have cis and trans backwards).

*(No you have not.)* This is depicted in $(3)$, but in this case a racemic mixture of the (*S,S*)- and (*R,R*)-product is formed, depending on which carbon atom in the bromonium ion the nucleophilic attack takes place.

> The only other isomer I can think of is 1,1-dibromo-2,2-dichloroethane, but it is not made from adding $\ce{Br2}$ to dichloroethene.

For completeness, this is depicted in $3$.

I could further think of another isomer, which is like the above not formed via addition, it is depicted in $(5)$. Note that these last two reactions also yield achiral products.

[image]